# Running Django server via Dockerfile on GAE Flex Custom runtime

Tags: django, google-app-engine, dockerfile, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy my Docker container with Django server on Google APP Engine Custom environment,
although it gets deployed but it doesn't start working the way it should work i.e it seems django runserver is not working .

app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: jobs
resources: 
   cpu: 4
   memory_gb: 8
   disk_size_gb: 30
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM hsingh1993/jobs:fourth
EXPOSE 8000/tcp
RUN id
USER jovyan
WORKDIR /home/jovyan/trustdjobs
CMD ["python","./manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Update 1:

```
KeyError: 'scrappy'

        at call_command (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py:103)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Please provide the full stack trace and modify your post with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your django application is not configured properly, Check urls.py under project to see path defined. Your Django is working properly but when you go on to the app engine URL .